# Installing Apache Hadoop on OpenStack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, openstack

I have successfully configured OpenStack following the tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/).

I have searched a lot about instaling Apache Hadoop on OpenStack but could not find the way to install.

Can anyone suggest me how do I configure Apache Hadoop on OpenStack?

Answer (score 3):

The [Sahara Project](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Savanna) (ex Savanna Project) is an initiative to provision Hadoop on top of OpenStack

They provide an [installation guide](https://savanna.readthedocs.org/en/0.3/userdoc/installation.guide.html).